# space character lost in dropdownlist

Tags: html, asp.net, sql-server-2008, drop-down-menu, spaces

I Have DropDown List which the value generated from SQL Database

here's my DropDown List :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dropProb" AppendDataBoundItems="true" EnableViewState="false"
      runat="server" DataSourceID="Prob" DataTextField="val" DataValueField="Value2">
       <Items>
           <asp:ListItem Text="None" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
        </Items>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="Prob" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:DispatchConnectionString %>"
SelectCommand="SELECT (rtrim(value2) + space(15 - len(value2)) + Value3) as val,Value2 FROM [Parameter] WHERE ([ParamType] = @ParamType) ">
<SelectParameters>
   <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="PROB" Name="ParamType" Type="String" />
     </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I use :

```
SELECT (rtrim(value2) + space(15 - len(value2)) + Value3) as val,Value2 FROM [Parameter] WHERE ([ParamType] = @ParamType)
```

to get the value to displayed on the drop downlist, it should have space according my query,

but unfortunately it didn't show the space, here's the picture :

[image]

but if I run the Sql Query it's give me the result what I want :

[image]

is it something wrong with my dropdownlist code? or it couldn't show the space character?

Comment: I want to give space betweiin this to value (rtrim(value2) + space(15 - len(value2)) + Value3) as val but the space didn't show on my dropdown list?

Comment: maybe putting "+'(literallyspace)'+" in between your 2 values can solve it?

Comment: at first I try to put the 'space' in my value but still didn't show up..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must replace empty spaces to &nbps; in order for html to render your spaces correctly

```
    SELECT REPLACE(
    (rtrim(value2) + space(15 - len(value2)) + Value3),
    ' ',
    '&nbsp;'
    ) as val,
    Value2
    FROM [Parameter]
    WHERE ([ParamType] = @ParamType)
```

Comment: Ah, never thought about replacing `''` to `'&nbsp;'`